# SQL - Get Several Date Days Ago (Exclude Saturday and Sunday)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get date 7 days ago from 20 October 2017, exclude weekend. If 20 October 2017 is Friday, 7 days ago means 11 October 2017. How is the query for that problem?

The desired result is:

```
2017-10-19
2017-10-18
2017-10-17
2017-10-16
2017-10-13
2017-10-12
2017-10-11
```

Comment: please show us what you have tired on your own.. this is not a code service provider site...

Comment: Check out the `DateTime.AddDays` method and `DateTime.DayOfWeek` property.  With that and a loop you should be able to generate the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check needed period on how excluded days it has. 
For example, we need take period from today to day before 7 day ago. 
X (finded date) = Y (now date) - Z (7 days, ago period). 
Then we try check this period Z day by day [from 12/10 till 19/10]. In result we have found 2 days and decrease this from Y day.

For linq I we can write this function:

```
    private DateTime GetBeforeDateExcludeWeekends(DateTime FromDate, int Period)
    {
        DateTime tillBeforeDate = FromDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(Period));

        var weekendDayCnt = 
            Enumerable.Range(0, (FromDate - tillBeforeDate).Days + 1).Select(d => tillBeforeDate.AddDays(d))
            .Where(day => day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            .Count();

        return FromDate.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(Period + weekendDayCnt));
    }
```

Sorry for my bad english. =)